# Return the contribution of source nodes in NetworkX directed graph

Tags: tree, nodes, networkx

I have a directed NetworkX graph that connects supply nodes with one another via edges, for which capacity attribute values are defined.

I am interested in obtaining a list of root nodes as I specify a source/sink node.
I manage to obtain a tree by using the depth first search method `nx.dfs_tree(G, sink node)`

However, I would like to:

- Get a list of all the source nodes and their overall contribution in provisioning the sink node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by overall contribution of a source node in provisioning the sink node you mean the sum of capacity for each edge in the shortest path between source and sink, then:

```
contributions = nx.shortest_path_length(G, target=sink_node, weight='capacity')
paths = nx.shortest_path(G, target=sink_node, weight='capacity')
intermediary_nodes = set()
for node in paths:
    intermediary_nodes.update(paths[node][1:])
sources = [(node, contribution) for node, contribution in contributions.items() if node not in intermediary_nodes]
```

will do the job. Where `sources` is a list of 2-tuples of the kind (source, overall contribution). Nodes not *contributing* are ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does seem to work. However, I do find nodes in the results that are not source nodes, but just intermediaries. Is it possible to only have end-nodes and their contributions? By end-nodes/source nodes, I understand nodes that are not the target of any other nodes.

Comment: @RomainSacchi You can then note the intermediary nodes to ignore them too when selecting the sources (as in the edit above).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.